# What part does the "token" play in password reset?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I'm using laravel's Auth password reset method and not sure i fully understand what part plays the token in all of this.

1. I'm sending the user an email with `Password::remind('email@email.com')` , which generates a token in my `password_reminders` table. The token is fully visible in the url.
2. The user goes to a url that looks something like: `mywebsite.com/remindpass/xxxxxx[token]` .
3. Then he fills out a form with his `email` and a new `password` , sending it trough post to a controller - which uses `Password::reset('email','password','xxxxxx')` .

The question is how is this secure? What does the generated token do to prevent someone just going to  `mywebsite.com/remindpass/xxxxxx[token]` and change the email & password as he likes?

Can someone please clarify the proccess?

Comment: As far as I know, it does nothing to prevent that. I think it's just that "someone" doesn't know the token and that it expires after a while what makes it "secure enough".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure someone could answer this question better than I could.

Short answer:

The token makes it more difficult for someone to guess the credentials needed to reset the password while making the reset link in the email available.

Long answer:

In the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php`, you'll see the method `createRememberTokenIfDoesntExist`. This method actually references another method right above it called `refreshRememberToken` to set your token.

It uses the laravel helper function `str_random`. If you trace this function back to it's source, you'll find it uses the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php` class' `random` method.

```
public static function random($length = 16)
{
    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes'))
    {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length * 2);

        if ($bytes === false)
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to generate random string.');
        }

        return substr(str_replace(array('/', '+', '='), '', base64_encode($bytes)), 0, $length);
    }

    return static::quickRandom($length);
}
```

Now we finally get down to where the token is built. This method uses the function `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`to generate the token. You can read about that function in the PHP manual page for [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php), but basically it generates a cryptographically strong random string.

Laravel then takes this string (still in the random method), base 64 encodes it, replaces some characters, and takes a slice of that string based on either the default setting of 16 (seen in the parameter definition `$length = 16`) or whatever length is passed into the method by the caller.

So, you get a string that is cryptographically strong and then manipulated as your token.

If you look at the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/DatabaseUserProvider.php` and find the method `retrieveByToken`, you'll see that laravel uses both the user record ID and the token to find the user who's password needs to change.

For someone to guess that string AND the id of you user record that has that token would be incredibly difficult and would require knowledge of your application's business logic.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the generated token do to prevent someone just going to `mywebsite.com/remindpass/xxxxxx[token]` and change the email & password as he likes?

Because only you and the person you sent the email to (i.e. the account holder) know what the token is.

A strong implementation will takes steps to make it hard to guess tokens:

- Long (harder to guess) tokens
- Time limited tokens
- IP based rate limiting for access to `/remindpass/*`